# Mysql root user always shows access denied from any operations

Tags: mysql, root

I have been facing this problem quite a while. I have installed xampp in indeed installed php and mysql. mysql always comes with default user root ( no password). Im able to login by using root ( no password) but it is not letting me to do anything. use any db, select any table, change password.. it is not letting me to do any of these operation. If try im getting a message

```
mysql> use mysql
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'
mysql>
```

Let me show you the steps that I did here..

Login was success.

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql.exe -u root;
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 5
Server version: 5.5.27 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

I ran this to see users list

```
mysql> select user();
+-----------------+
| user()          |
+-----------------+
| root;@localhost |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Fine i ran this too

```
mysql> select current_user();
+----------------+
| current_user() |
+----------------+
| @localhost     |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I don't know why it is not showing as root@localhost, is it the right way?

Then interestingly the below message shows

```
mysql> show grants;
+--------------------------------------+
| Grants for @localhost                |
+--------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ''@'localhost' |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Grant USAGE ... is it right?

it is just stopped me from doing anything from DB.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.fosspedia.com/mysql-error-1044-42000-access-denied-for-user-localhost/ It helped me with the same problem. Not enough to post a good answer, though :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql.exe -u root;
```

Try this:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql.exe -u root -p
```

And hit Enter, dont put a semicolon at the end, just hit enter; if you dont have a password, just hit enter.

Now when you make this:

```
select user();
```

Its going to show :

```
root@localhost
```

Instead of:

```
//you are logged in as the root user; instead of some "root;" user. 
root;@localhost
```

Comment: I believe he shouldn't be even able to login if he didn't enter his password? He should directly get `Access denied` and no console access, isn't that right?

Comment: If you have a blank password you can login that way

Comment: It is not letting me to. I did enter the same way as you mentioned. It shows me a big list but did not move to mysql>. Hence i will get a message of "'select' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." while executing the Select User();

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to access MySQL through Vagrant. While running `SELECT CURRENT_USER();` I also got 1 row result of `@localhost`.

The solution was to launch MySQL in the following manner:

`mysql -u root -p;` - running this will prompt you for a password, in which case I typed `root`, press Enter and I was logged in as actual root and was able to execute commands as expected.